# Inserting element in a linked list with Pascal

Tags: linked-list, pascal, freepascal

I've seen some algorithms designed to append an elment at the end of a linked list here and browsing other website, then I wrote a small procedure that i believe it should append a given element at the end of the list but it doesn't seems to work.
My question here is, why it doesn't work?

I defined pointers and nodes as follows:

```
 Pointer = ^Node;
Node = record
    about : element;
    next : Pointer;
end;
```

And the following procedure receives a linked list L and a q element that should be appended to the end of L

First I define the record that I'll insert afterwards

```
var INS : Poniter;
........
INS.about := q;
```

And the procedure goes as follows:

```
{temp := L}  {I'll use this for my attempt below }
if L<>NIL then
begin
  while L^.next<>NIL do
  begin 
  L:= L^.next;
  end;
  L^.next := INS;
  INS^.next := NIL; 
  {L:=temp;} {I'll explain this in my attempt below}
end
else
 begin
  L:= INS;
 end;
```

I also have a small procedure that prints all the elements of the linked list

```
 procedure displayElements(L : pointer);

 begin
  while L <> nil do
  begin
   writeln(L^.about);
   L := L^.next;
   end
 end;
```

The problem: after i run de program it only displays the last two entries of the list.

Conjecture about the problem: I believe it only shows the last two because when i run the procedure displayElements the pointer L is already one element before NIL -because i used the second algorithm-.

Attempt to a solution: Alright, i think i need to put L back at the very first place so that when i use displayElements it get all the elements in the list. But how could I do that?, I tried what i commented above saving L in temp but it didn't work.

Any ideas?. Thanks.

Comment: What's the header for the insert procedure? Are you using inserting into a local variable or a global? BTW, the 'INS^.next := NIL' line should be where you initialise INS, which you didn't show. It also doesn't help that you seem to be redefining the type 'pointer'.

Comment: The header: procedure Insert(q : integer; L : Pointer).
I agree that I should put 'INS^.next := NIL', but where did I redefine the type 'pointer'?.

Comment: at the beginning of your code, you wrote "I defined pointers and nodes as follows: pointer = ^node".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very simple program which will do what you want. Maintaining a 'tail' pointer means that you don't have to traverse the list every time that you want to add a value. If this were your code, then you would be missing the 'tail:= tmp' line in Insert: without this, Display prints the first and last entries, but not those in the middle.

```
type
 node = ^MyRec;
 MyRec = record
          value: integer;
          next: node
         end;

var
 head, tail: node;

Procedure Insert (v: integer);
var
 tmp: node;

begin
 new (tmp);
 tmp^.value:= v;
 tmp^.next:= nil;
 if head = nil
  then head:= tmp
  else tail^.next:= tmp;
 tail:= tmp;
end;

Procedure Display;
var
 tmp: node;

begin
 tmp:= head;
 while tmp <> nil do
  begin
   writeln (tmp^.value);
   tmp:= tmp^.next
  end;
end;

begin
 head:= nil;
 Insert (5);
 Insert (10);
 Display;
 Insert (15);
 Display;
 readln
end.
```

**[Edit]**

Judging by your comments, some further explanation is required. [Professorial mode on] When I started programming some thirty years ago (OMSI Pascal on a PDP 11/70), linked lists and pointers appeared in every self-respecting program, but since the rise of Delphi in 1990, such complexities have been hidden and most programmers now never see a naked pointer.

Linked lists come in different formats: the simple and the complex. The simple types differ at the points of insertion and deletion: a stack inserts and deletes at the same end, a queue inserts at one end and deletes at the other, a list allows insertion and deletion at any place. More complex types are trees and graphs. Your question is asking about the implementation of a *queue* - insertion is always at the rear, deletion is at the front.

In order to implement this properly, we need two variables: 'head' points to the head of the queue and 'tail' points to the end of the queue. These variables are normal global variables; memory is allocated for them in the data segment of the program. A pointer is a simple variable whose value is the *memory address of another variable*. Initially, 'head' does not point to anything so its value is nil (think of this as 0).

Normally in textbooks, the construction of a queue is accompanied by little boxes showing how memory is allocated, but I don't know how to do that here and so the explanation will be a little wordy.

When the first insertion occurs, the memory manager in the run time system allocates 12 bytes *from the heap* and sets the value of the local variable 'tmp' to be the address of the first of those 12 bytes (this is 'new (tmp)'). Of those 12 bytes, the 'value' part is set to 5 and the 'next' part is set to nil. Then the program checks what the value of 'head' is: if it is nil, then the value (ie address of the memory block allocated above) is copied from 'tmp' to 'head'. If 'head' already points to something, then the value of 'tmp' is copied to 'tail^.next' (which previously would have been nil). Then the value of 'tmp' is copied to the tail variable. Thus 'head' *always* points to the beginning of the queue and does not change whereas 'tail' points to the end of the queue and changes every time a new node is inserted.

Let's do some debugging:

```
When the program starts, head = nil, tail is undefined
After 'insert (5)', head = $870874, tail = $870874
After 'insert (10)', head = $870874, tail = $870880 
After 'insert (15)', head = $870874, tail = $87088C
```

When displaying,

```
tmp:= head ......... tmp = $870874  (ie head)
tmp:= tmp^.next .... tmp = $870880
tmp:= tmp^.next .... tmp = $87088C
tmp:= tmp^.next .... tmp = nil
```

If your program has more than one queue, then you will need two variables for each queue, and 'Insert' will have to be changed in order to accept two parameters (which will be the head and tail of the given queue).

There is no need to write 'new (head)' and 'new (tail)' - doing so will cause the original pointers to the beginning and end of the queue to be lost.

[Professorial mode off] I hope that this explanation helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm sorry i didn't put the header of Insert but it supposed to be Insert(v:integer,L:list), i'm inserting the new values in a given list, that's why i moved to the last element of the list. I did another try: (1) new(tail), new(head), new(tmp); (2)head := L [saving the first value of the list]; (3) while L^.sig<>nil do L:= L^.sig [getting the last value]; (4) tail := L [saving the tail], (5) tmp.value := v; (6) tmp^.next := nil, (7) tails^.next := tmp;[inserting the following value] (8) L:=head [back to the first one].

Your code works, but this returns an error. Why?
Thanks!

Comment: @Trash: Don't write 'new (tail); new (head)'. These are supposed to be global pointers which point to elements within the list,  whereas you are creating new ones every time. Try drawing a little box diagram to see how the list is created.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! :)
I deleted the new(head), new(tails) and with some small changes it finally worked, now i can finish the whole problem -following Polya's advice, this was de 'easier' case because i have to insert an element at any point of the list according to some criteria (i already did the function for it)-. I guess that to insert [INS] between [L] and [L.next] i could just do [L]->[INS] and then [INS]->[L.next], right?.
Thanks a lot for your explanation, it was really helpful!.